# Google Apps Script runs very slow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code that pulls data from firebase database and fills out the data in a google sheets document.
The process takes around 1 second per row, and there are 1000 rows.

Is my code not very efficient, or is there a better way to fill out information row by row on a google sheet?

```
function getAllData() {
  var firebaseUrl = "url-here";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();
  var iterator = 0
  var obje = []
  //Logger.log(data)
  for(var i in data) {
    iterator++;
    if (iterator > 5) {
      break
    }

    if (data[i] !== null) {
      Logger.log(data[i]);
      obje.push(data[i]) 
    }
  }

     var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A5:K5");
    range.setBackground("red");


     //Set Column Names 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A5').setValue('Key');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B5').setValue('Time');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C5').setValue('Location');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D5').setValue('Participant_1');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E5').setValue('Participant_2');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F5').setValue('Category');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G5').setValue('team1Score');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('H5').setValue('team2Score');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I5').setValue('gameDetails');


  var number = 5
  Logger.log(obje.length);
  for (var i in obje) {
    Logger.log('Hello' + i)
    number++


      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + number + ":K" + number);
        range.setBackground("lightblue");
      }
    else {
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + number + ":K" + number);
        range.setBackground("lightgreen");
    }

    //Populate Row Data
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A' + number).setValue(obje[i].Key);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + number).setValue(obje[i].Time);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C' + number).setValue(obje[i].Location);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D'+ number).setValue(obje[i].Participant_1);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E'+ number).setValue(obje[i].Participant_2);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F'+ number).setValue(obje[i].Category);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G'+ number).setValue(obje[i].team1Score);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('H'+ number).setValue(obje[i].team2Score);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I'+ number).setValue(obje[i].gameDetails);
  }
}
```

Comment: Each call of getRange reads and in your case writes back to the file.  You need to minimize those calls.  See this Googls Apps Script blog post on [Optimizing Spreadsheet Operations](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a 2d array then this should work.  **Nope this won't work**.  I went and learned something about Firebase Today and I see now that it's an array of objects so I'll figure out how to make the work and come back and correct it. I'm guessing I'll have to do it a line at and time.

```
function getAllData() 
{
  var firebaseUrl = "url-here";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();//I assume this is correct I have not used firebase
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var headers=['Key','Time','Locaton','Participant_1','Participant_2','Category','teams1Score','team2Score','gameDetails'];
  sh.appendRow(headers);
  sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,headers.length).setValues(data);
}
```

## This is working

Here's a link to an [example from another contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39200338/7215091) but I couldn't get that to work. So I modified it a little below:

```
function writeMySheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var firebaseUrl = "https://PROJECTID.firebaseio.com/";
  var secret = "SECRET";  
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl,secret);
  var data = base.getData();
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  var sheetRow = [];
  var entryKeys;
  var firstTime=true;
  for (index in keys) {
    sheetRow = [];
    entryKeys = Object.keys(data[keys[index]])
    for (i in entryKeys) {
      sheetRow.push(data[keys[index]][entryKeys[i]]);
    }
    //Logger.log(sheetRow);
    if(firstTime)
    {
      sheet.appendRow(entryKeys);//Prints column headers
      firstTime=false;
    }
    sheet.appendRow(sheetRow);                            
  }
}
```

And this seems to works on the tutorial data from the [QuickStart tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684710/7215091) that I thought I'd never get to work.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out another way though!