# Can't Get Firebase Google App Script Quickstart Tutorial to Work

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database

I can't seem to get the [Firebase QuickStart](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script) to work for me.  I'm pretty sure that I followed all of the instructions correctly.  But I'm not getting access to write to the database.  And according to the instructions the database is currently open to the public with the suggest rules change displayed below.  Has anybody ever gone through this tutorial before? I'd like a hint as to what to do next.

Here's the code.

```
  function writeDataToFirebase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rV2_S2q5rcakOuHs2E1iLeKR2floRIozSytAt2iRXo8");
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//I tried running it with data in this spreadsheet copied from the recommended source
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var firstName = data[i][0];
    var lastName = data[i][1];
    dataToImport[firstName + '-' + lastName] = {
      firstName:firstName,
      lastName:lastName,
      emailAddress:data[i][2],
      country:data[i][4],
      department:data[i][5],
      weight:data[i][6],
      birthDate:data[i][7]
    };
  }
  var firebaseUrl = "https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  base.setData("", dataToImport);
}
```

The Data:

[image]

This is my library dialog:

[image]

This is the error I keep on getting:

[image]

This name of my script in the FireBase Site:

[image]

This is the access rules change:

[image]

Comment: Is this your database? `https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/`. And you're saying that it stays empty?

Comment: I think I just found out that the url is supposed to be `https://projectId/firebaseio.com`.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not getting an error when I use the project id from Firebase Console but I still don't see any data on the site.

Comment: A bit of a comedy of errors on my side.  Yes script-examples is supposed to be replaced with projectId that you can get at the Firebase console Settings/General/ProjectId.  And then it works.

Comment: Good to hear. I was already surprised that you got that database name, which I assume is Romain's. :-)  I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: I appreciate your effort in helping me.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess I missed an important point.  The url of firebase database has your projectId in it.  So the url would be something like `https://' + projectId + '.firebaseio.com'`.  Sorry, to bother everyone with such a simple question.